# How to read an xlsx or xls file from a URL

Tags: ruby, excel, xls, xlsx, open-uri

I'm trying to open a file from a URL using roo (1.11.0)

```
Foobazs-iMac:pipeline foobazlabs$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'roo'
require '=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Roo::Excelx.new(open("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xPxn6cu3RZuQdgrx4y72"))
NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for #<Tempfile:0x007ffd091d25c8>
```

but it looks like there isn't support for this using roo (it accepts only path names)

Can't use a temp file path name either

```
irb(main):004:0> t = Tempfile.new('temp.xlsx')
=> #<File:/var/folders/q_/q738l9cj3xl90yfs1g8wc4200000gn/T/temp.xlsx20130317-2753-1p3l5l6>
irb(main):005:0> t.binmode
irb(main):006:0> open("https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xPxn6cu3RZuQdgrx4y72") { |data| t.write   data.read }
=> 13494
irb(main):007:0> Roo::Excelx.new(t.path)
use Roo::Excelx.new to handle .xlsx spreadsheet files. This has .xlsx20130317-2753-1p3l5l6
TypeError: /var/folders/q_/q738l9cj3xl90yfs1g8wc4200000gn/T/temp.xlsx20130317-2753-1p3l5l6 is not an Excel-xlsx file
```

Any Ruby library/gem that I can use for this purpose? I only need to read xls and xlsx files. I don't need to write. Since I'm on Heroku, I can only use Tempfiles not actual Files.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the url without `open`? According to the documentation, the way you're supposed to instantiate a new `Excel` object is as follows: `oo = Excel.new("http://www.somedomain.com/simple_spreadsheet.xls")`

Comment: I fixed it by removing the check for .xlsx extension in roo. Of course, the use case ensures that it is always an .xlsx file so it works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you have in mind, but I use two packages to read xls and xlsx files, which are more common than I would like.

- read.xlsx in xlsx uses Java, works most of the time.  I don't think it reads straight from a url, I usually download.file first.
- read.xls in gdata uses Perl (download if you uses Windows, otherwise automatic), and reads straight from a url.  Here's an example that reads in a file from the UN population projections:

  library("gdata")
  url <- "http://esa.un.org/unpd/wpp/Excel-Data/DB04_Population_ByAgeSex_Annual/WPP2010_DB4_F1B_POPULATION_BY_AGE_BOTH_SEXES_ANNUAL_2011-2100.XLS"
  data <- read.xls(url, sheet=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RemoteTable](https://github.com/seamusabshere/remote_table) for XLSX, XLS, CSV, and other formats:

```
require 'remote_table'
RemoteTable.new('https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xPxn6cu3RZuQdgrx4y72', format: :xlsx).each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Gives you:

```
{"Name"=>"Kristina H. Chung", "E-mail"=>"cheenu.madan@gmail.com", "Phone"=>"8032696336.0", "Org"=>"ABCD"}
{"Name"=>"Paige H. Chen", "E-mail"=>"cheenu.madan@gmail.com", "Phone"=>"7502167067.0", "Org"=>"ABCD"}
{"Name"=>"Sherri E. Melton", "E-mail"=>"cheenu.madan@gmail.com", "Phone"=>"7044576998.0", "Org"=>"ABCD"}
{"Name"=>"Gretchen I. Hill", "E-mail"=>"cheenu.madan@gmail.com", "Phone"=>"7967784377.0", "Org"=>"ABCD"}
{"Name"=>"Karen U. Puckett", "E-mail"=>"cheenu.madan@gmail.com", "Phone"=>"9151299999.0", "Org"=>"ABCD"}
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ride of the NoMethod error (undefined method `start_with?`) by adding an additional `to_s` string conversion to the path:

```
Roo::Excelx.new(path.to_s)
```

In my case it was an uploaded Excel file which I tried to process with the Roo gem, though

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here works for me, but this yes(for xlsx):

```
file =  Roo::Excelx.new(params[:file].path,nil, :ignore)
```

from: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast